# Jquery button text switching

Tags: jquery

What would be the best way to toggle text on several anchors in JQuery? For example what I'm trying to do is let's say all anchors on a page say "click me".  When anchor one is clicked the text changes to "I'm clicked" (or whatever).  Then if anchor two is clicked the text changes on that anchor, and the text for anchor one is reset back to "click me".  So no matter if a anchor is clicked once, then a different anchor is clicked, or clicked twice, the text will change accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your code will be like this

```
<a href="#" class="click">click me</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="click">click me</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="click">click me</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="click">click me</a><br/>
```

add following jquery

```
$(function(){

    $('.click').click(function(){
        $('.click').text("click me");
        if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(this).removeClass('clicked').text("click me");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('clicked').text("I'm clicked");
        }
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

Comment: This works except for the fact that when button 1 is clicked, the text switches, but if pressed again it does not switch back

Comment: @user1568811, check it nowm i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge of your HTML, you probably want something like this:

```
var $a = $('a');
$a.on('click', function() {
    $a.text('Click me');
    $(this).text('I\'m clicked');
});
```